# How Do I import emails in outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, thunderbird, import

I have converted all my Mac Thunderbird emails to .pst format using thunderbird to pst converter application which I got from here http://thunderbirdtopst.com/. I am completely confused with the import function as I am new to the windows platform. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

#### How Do I import emails (.pst file) into outlook 2010?

> **How to import .pst file data into Outlook**
>
> You can use the backup copy of your .pst file to restore your Outlook
>   data if the original .pst file is damaged or lost. Everything that is
>   saved in the .pst file is returned to Outlook.
>
> In Outlook 2010:
>
> Follow these steps to restore, or import, your data into Outlook:
>
> 1. Click the File tab.
> 2. In the Open category, click Import.
> 3. In the Import and Export Wizard, click Import from another program or file, and then click Next.
> 4. Click Outlook Data File (.pst), and then click Next.
> 5. Type the path and the name of the .pst file that you want to import, or click Browse to choose the file to import.
>
> Note Under Options, it is recommended that you click Do not import
>   duplicates, unless you want the imported information to replace or
>   duplicate items that are already in Outlook.
>
> 6. Click Next.
> 7. Select the folder that you want to import. To import everything in the .pst file, select the top of the hierarchy.
>
> Note The top folder (usually Personal Folders, Outlook Data File or
>   your email address) is selected automatically. Include subfolders is
>   selected by default. All folders under the folder selected will be
>   imported
>
> 8. Click Finish.

Source [How to manage .pst files in Microsoft Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287070)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is quite easy. Here is the step-by-step tutorial on how to import your PSTs into Outlook:

1. Click File > Open & Export > Import/Export.
   This starts the Import and Export Wizard.

   2. Choose Import from another program or file, and then click Next.
   3. Choose Outlook Data File (.pst) and click Next.
   4. Browse to the .pst file you want to import.
   5. Under Options, choose how you want to deal with duplicates
   6. Click Next.
   7. If a password was assigned to the Outlook Data File (.pst), enter the password, and then click OK.
   8. Set the options for importing items. The default settings usually don’t need to be changed.
   9. Click Finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to import your PST data in Outlook 2010.

1. Select the File tab. Then click on Open and select the Import option.
2. In the Import and Export Wizard select the option of Import from another program or file.
3. After selecting Next, select Outlook PST file and then click on Next.
4. Select Browse to select the file to import.
5. Then click on Next and select the folder that you want to import. To import everything in the PST file, select the top of the hierarchy.
6. After this select Finish.

Now, your data has been imported into Outlook 2010.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.